# Get registered algorithms from jwt

Tags: python, algorithm, token, jwt

I want to know if an algorithm is already registered in python JWT because my app throws an error when trying it twice.

I tried to register `ES256`at runtime as a workaround for an exception thrown after upgrading from PyJWT `0.3.0` to `1.1.0` like this:

```
jwt.register_algorithm(ALGO_ES256, ECAlgorithm(ECAlgorithm.SHA256))
```

This works perfectly. Now I have to call the script where this happens more then once and got an Exception, that I can not register it twice.

I thought about evaluating the already registered values before registering a new one and found out that the algorithms are contained in:

```
jwt.api._jwt_global_obj
```

How can I access that global object?
I'd like to do something like:

```
if ALGO_ES256 not in jwt.api._jwt_global_obj:
    jwt.register_algorithm(ALGO_ES256, ECAlgorithm(ECAlgorithm.SHA256))
```

But it keeps telling me it can not find referece for `api`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases the algorithm is already registered for your key. E.g. if you have the cryptography module installed.

You should unregister the existing algorithm first to make sure it uses the old one everytime:

```
from jwt.api import _jwt_global_obj
from jwt.contrib.algorithms.py_ecdsa import ECAlgorithm

if ALGO_ES256 in _jwt_global_obj._algorithms:
    jwt.unregister_algorithm(ALGO_ES256)
jwt.register_algorithm(ALGO_ES256, ECAlgorithm(ECAlgorithm.SHA256))
```